# Is there anyway to know what type of base operating system (ubuntu, alpine, redhat) a Docker Image is using, without needing to run it?

Tags: docker, operating-system, system

I am trying to figure out the names and how many packages are present in an Ubuntu based image in DockerHub. I can find it after running the image on my computer and running the command "dpkg -l". But the commands will be different if the image is alpine or redhat based.
Is there a way to know, without running it? That way I can write a script that can find the package info, with respect to the type of operating system the Docker image posess. The docker inspect command does not correctly return it.

Thanks in advance.

I tried to run docker inspect, but it did not work

Comment: Clearly off-topic on SO.  Perhaps: https://devops.stackexchange.com or https://forums.docker.com or https://superuser.com.

Comment: Note that you don't really want to know the OS for your use case. You want to know which package manager is in use. For example Debian and Ubuntu both use apt/dpkg, CentOS and SuSE use rpm, ... There's a lot more distributions than there are package managers out there

Answer (score 1):

A Docker image doesn't necessarily contain an OS as such. It might just contain an executable. The `hello-world` image on Docker Hub is such an image.

However if the image does contain the libraries and executables from a distribution, usually it also has the file `/etc/os-release` which contains information about the distribution.

To find out which distribution the image is based on, you can run the command

```
docker run --rm <image name> cat /etc/os-release
```

For the `alpine:latest` image, that will print

```
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.17.2
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.17"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues"
```

But like I said, it won't work on all images.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I might be able to find a workaround with your hint. One script to find out the based image by filtering the ID. Another to list packages based on the distribution. Thanks.